# MAMP 3, .htaccess and php_value

Tags: php, apache, mamp, mamp-pro

Hy

I've updated my mamp2 to 3.
after that i'll get the following error in apache (2.2.5)

```
[Wed Mar 12 09:10:58 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Mar 12 09:10:58 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 13431)
[Wed Mar 12 09:10:58 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Mar 12 09:10:58 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 12 09:11:07 2014] [alert] [client 10.241.101.148] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev/application/sites/mypage/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

apache 2.2.5 /
php version: 5.3.14

htaccess

```
php_value   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  1
php_value   html_errors On
php_value   xdebug.scream 0

php_value   display_errors  on
php_value   error_reporting 1023

php_value   xdebug.max_nesting_level 150

php_value   upload_max_filesize 70M
php_value   post_max_size 75M

AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/opentype otf
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff

php_value   newrelic.appname                                "myapp.ch.dev"
php_flag    newrelic.enabled                                on
php_flag    newrelic.browser_monitoring.auto_instrument     off
```

some ideas? i'm not that fit in apache configs. thanks

Answer (score 7):

php_value and php_flag aren't allowed directives in your .htaccess file if you're running MAMP's php in CGI mode.

Assuming you're using MAMP Pro, go to the Main MAMP window's PHP tab and make sure that "Mode" is set to "Identical PHP version for all hosts (module)". Restart your MAMP server and your .htaccess overrides should be ok.

If you must run PHP in CGI mode, you can put the overrides directly into your php.ini file instead.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer forever; thank you @r.aubin

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `php_value` on all other servers except your local one and you really want to use PHP in CGI mode (as it was in my case), you can locally use `php.ini` file and add special condition inside your `.htaccess` file to keep it in repository etc. while still avoiding 500s.

For instance by using this snippet of code:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
    php_value post_max_size 200M
</IfModule>
```

you use `php_value` only when it's possible (PHP as a module).